# Is all energy quantised?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, spacetime, discrete

1. I'm wondering if all energy is quantized?
2. Can a particle with kinetic energy have any value of kinetic energy or is kinetic energy also quantized?
3. My reason for asking this is that if a particle is travelling through space it travelling through a certain number of Planck lengths per second, would this not mean it's velocity is quantized?

Apologies if this is a badly worded question,I'm only in High School.

Comment: Energy isn't quantised the way you're thinking. Light has a quantum nature, wherein photon energy is given as E=hf. Energy is equal to Planck's constant of action multiplied by frequency. But note that a photon can have _any_ value of energy. In similar vein an electron can move at any speed, and have any kinetic energy you like. Planck's constant of action isn't anything to do with Planck length.

Comment: I'll add that there is no evidence for the existence of the planck length because we have no evidence for the quantization of space.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Kinetic energy is never quantized in a moving system, but always appears as continuous spectrum in the spectrum of the Hamiltonian, which describes the possible total energies of a system.